# Undefined method 'size' for #<File:text.txt> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

This is the code I am running, it does fine until I get to line 15. The command I run is: `ruby ex16.rb text.txt`. This is a practice sample I'm writing which is meant to be a simple little text editor:

```
filename = ARGV.first
script = $0

puts "We're going to erase #{filename}."
puts "if you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
puts "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

print "? "
STDIN.gets

puts "Opening the file..."
target = File.open(filename, 'w')

puts "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate(target.size)

puts "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

print "line 1: "; line1 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line 2: "; line2 = STDIN.gets.chomp()
print "line 3: "; line3 = STDIN.gets.chomp()undefined method 'size'

puts "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

puts "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using, and on what platform? If you want to erase the file contents, why not just do target.truncate(0) ?

Comment: Same error in 1.8.6, works in 1.9.2. Strange because the pickaxe 1.8 says nothing special about File.size.

Comment: Diego - this is a practice exercise i was asked to write.

Comment: Bernard - version 1.8.7..I think I should move up to 1.9.2. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, if you open a file for write acces, it is already truncated to zero.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour of `size` has changed between versions ! It's a class method in 1.8 and both class and instance method in 1.9.

```
print '-----File.instance_methods'; p File.instance_methods.sort.grep(/^si/)
print '-----File.singleton_methods'; p File.singleton_methods.sort.grep(/^si/)

case RUBY_VERSION
when '1.8.6'
    puts '1.8.6 '; p File.size('t.rb')
when '1.9.2'
    puts '1.9.2 '; p File.open('t.rb').size
    puts '1.9.2 '; p File.size('t.rb')
else
    puts 'not for this version'
end

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.6 (2010-09-02 patchlevel 420) [i686-darwin12.2.0]
$ ruby -w t.rb
-----File.instance_methods["singleton_methods"]
-----File.singleton_methods["size", "size?"]
1.8.6 
334
```

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
$ ruby -w t.rb
-----File.instance_methods[:singleton_class, :singleton_methods, :size]
-----File.singleton_methods[:size, :size?]
1.9.2 
334
1.9.2 
376
```

PS : somebody down voted your question, probably because it's too long. Next time post only the line in error and the ones necessary to understand the line in question.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Bernard as well as the explanation for voting this down. will do better next time. Cheers.